# Mysql erro 1049 como resolver

Tags: mysql, linux

tinha acabado de instalar o mysql no ubuntu, depois reiniciei meu computador, quando tentei logar no mysql deu esse erro.

alguém pode me ajuda?

```
root@wladi-Dell-System-Vostro-3450:/# mysql -r root -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'root'
root@wladi-Dell-System-Vostro-3450:/#
```

Comment: O que você quer com o `-r`? Não seria `-u root`?

Comment: é isso mesmo. valeu

Answer (score 1):

A [opção `-r`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_raw) diz respeito a como determinados caracteres especiais devem ser escapados na saída do client. No seu comando, `root` está sendo interpretado como o nome da base de dados que você quer acessar. Acredito que você esteja querendo passar o usuário. Se for isso mesmo, use o seguinte comando:

```
mysql -u root
```